# Bulk Processing of S3 objects in Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, parallel-processing

A batch job needs to process over 4000 files stored in S3 bucket, these files are stored across 36 different prefix and each of these prefix will have internally have 4 sub prefix each.
Basically 36 root folders and each root folders having 4 subfolders which will be recreated in S3 bucket using prefixes.
 Each of these files location will be
stored in database which will be ready by lambda.
I am planning to use lambda here and want to process 6 root folders( S3 prefix) in 6 concurrent lambda, meaning I want to run same lambda concurrently.
I want to create a initializer lambda which will read all configuration of these folder structure from RDS and it will push 6 different SQS messages,
with each sqs message containing names of 6 root folders(S3 prefix) , i will create another lambda called processing lambda which will read SQS messages and starts processing 6 folders sequentially
within in the lambda.

Below are my questions:-

1. With 6 SQS message will the processing lambda be executed in concurrent mode?
2. Assuming average size of files is around 50kb , lambda will have read  each of these files in memory will this be an issue for processing in lambda
3. The SLA for job is around 10 min and the Batch job gets triggered every 20 min from 8am to 8pm, is Lambda right option or should this done using ECS

Comment: Note that you'll need to set a batch size of 1 to ensure that each SQS message is processed by a different Lambda function invocation. You could easily try all of this with a quick prototype. I'd recommend a large RAM configuration for the Lambda function to  ensure enough RAM to hold and process the object data and to give you more CPU and network.

Comment: Is ECS Service better option with multithreading

Comment: I really encourage you to use AWS Fargate instead of AWS lambdas

Comment: Job SLA has 10 min and its triggered every 20 min , fargate takes 60-90 seconds to download container, 90 seconds is wasted for download? is my understanding right or once it is downloaded CPU capacity of fargate is way better then lambda for processing and we can spawn multiple sub-process  within lambda using .net/java

Comment: AWS Lambda will be able to do what you seek. As to whether it can be done within a given time limit, that depends on how you are "processing" each file. If it is merely reading 4000 files with little processing required, it should work fine. The best way to confirm this is to implement it and see! You can create a Test event on the Lambda function to manually pass a "root folder" -- this will avoid the need to create the SQS part before you can test and time the function.

Comment: Thanks John, i will have to  do  operations like get list of filenames in S3, filter files with some extension , read the files in memory and convert one file format to other . Hope Lambda would be able  scale up for these operations

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look into distributed map offered my stepfunctions. I think it perfectly fits your need.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/step-functions-distributed-map-a-serverless-solution-for-large-scale-parallel-data-processing/